# Install Redis server in CentOS6 , how?

Tags: magento, caching, redis, centos6, directadmin

How to install redis server in CentOS 6 that installed DirectAdmin in it?
Did test several methods but no success!

I want use Redis for Magento Cache

Comment: Have you installed a gcc toolchain? Redis' `make` is normally the way to go (and very easy), see the README in the tar.

Comment: Yes installed , also redis installed as well with my last try, will update my Q tomorrow

Comment: OK. Please describe what's wrong, logs etcetera, otherwise ppl can't help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already installed `redis`, it is running and you are able to run `rediscli MONITOR` (which should say `OK`), you are probably missing the [`phpredis`](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) extension.

Usually this is easy to install, but in combination with DirectAdmin it requires some additional attention:

First, install `igbinary`, which will greatly improve your object serialisation experience.

`pecl install igbinary igbinary-devel` should do the trick, -but- on many CentOS systems the `/tmp` dir is mounted with `nosuid,noexec` which will prevent `phpize` from completing during the installation, because `pecl` will use `/tmp/pear/temp/` as the build-dir.

I fixed this by editing `/etc/fstab`:

```
   --- /dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp /tmp ext4 defaults,noatime,noexec,nosuid,errors=continue 1 2
   +++ /dev/mapper/vg_directadmin-lv_tmp /tmp ext4 defaults,noatime,errors=continue 1 2
```

and remounting `/tmp` with `mount -o remount /tmp`. After that `pecl install igbinary igbinary-devel` should work.

Next, download and install phpredis, using the `--enable-redis-igbinary` option. On my DirectAdmin installation the CLI `php` version as a different path than the one from DirectAdmin, so we'll explicitly use the DirectAdmin version which lives in `/usr/local/php5/`:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/tarball/0ae592b
tar xzvf 0ae592b
cd nicolasff-phpredis-0ae592b/
/usr/local/php5/bin/phpize
./configure --enable-redis-igbinary --with-php-config=/usr/local/php5/bin/php-config
make
make install
```

After that, your extension should be installed under `/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/` .

Last thing that remains is to edit `/usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` and add your new extensions to be loaded. Add:

```
extension=igbinary.so
extension=redis.so
```

Restart apache afterwards, and you should be done.

Comment: very complete and informative!
but pecl is not a necessary dependency, especially it is sometimes not included in directadmin custombuild packages. I suggest to change the flow to the make install flow as mentioned in the official site https://github.com/phadej/igbinary